# How do I stop Postgres copy command to stop padding Strings?

Tags: postgresql

My field is defined as follows

```
"COLUMNNAME" character(9)
```

I import CSV files using the following command

```
copy "TABLE" from '/my/directory' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

If I have a string such as `'ABCDEF'` Postgres pads it out to `'ABCDEF   '`.  How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is because you have char instead of varchar. change type of your column into varchar and everything will be fine

Comment: Yep.  The SQL Spec pretty clearly states that char(9) will be padded to 9 characters all the time.  Any db that doesn't do this is breaking the spec.